# How to calculate $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^2 - \tan^2(x)}{x^4}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, trigonometry, taylor-expansion

How do I calculate $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^2 - \tan^2(x)}{x^4}$? I just need a hint, not the entirely solution. Thank you in advance!

Comment: HInt: Difference of squares.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lhôpital-rule-or-series-expansion

Comment: Can you use L^Hopitlal's rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since$$x^2-\tan^2(x)=x^2-\left(x+\frac{x^3}3+o(x^4)\right)^2=-\frac23x^4+o(x^5)\ldots$$

---

Another possibility:$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2-\tan^2x}{x^4}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-\tan(x)}{x^3}\times\frac{x+\tan(x)}x.$$

Comment: You should have a $o(x^4)$ in the first equality (or a $O(x^5)$).

Comment: @G.S. Thanks. I've edited my answer. What do you think about the new one?

Comment: Jose, you corrected the wrong bracket! Once you square you can afford a $o(x^5)$. The other method might be simpler if OP does not know Taylor's expansions.

Comment: It is a bit confusing for me using the Taylor's expansion. I can solve it using the latter method. Thank you!

Comment: @G.S. Sure! Again, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Taylor's expansion of the tangent at $0$:

$$\tan(x) = x+\frac{x^3}{3} +o(x^3)\,.$$

Answer (score 1):

If we don't know the Taylor's expansion of the tangent then we can use the following L^Hospital.

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{x^2-\tan^2x}{x^4}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{2x-2\tan{x}\cdot\frac{1}{\cos^2x}}{4x^3}=$$
$$=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{x\cos^3x-\sin{x}}{2x^3}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\cos^3x-3x\cos^2x\sin{x}-\cos{x}}{6x^2}=$$
$$=-\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{3x\sin{x}\cos{x}+\sin^2x}{6x^2}=-\frac{3}{6}-\frac{1}{6}=-\frac{2}{3}.$$